# datePicker and validateDate condition in swift

Tags: swift, xcode, datepicker, swift4

I don't understand why isValid still false even if openDate equal to MINIMUM_Date. I used datePicker to get openDate value.

**Update**

I removed the time from the Date() and isValid returns true ,but if I input today date I'm getting yesterday date.

```
     func validateDate(openDate: Date) -> Bool {
                var isValid: Bool = true
          
                let MINIMUM_Date = Date()
                let MINIMUM_DateWithoutTime = MINIMUM_Date.removeTimeStamp.              
                if openDate <= MINIMUM_DateWithoutTime! {
                          isValid = false
                       }
          
                         return isValid
                     }
```

```
extension Date {
    public var removeTimeStamp : Date? {
       guard let date = Calendar.current.date(from: Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: self)) else {
        return nil
       }
       return date
   }
}
```

Comment: When is MINIMUM_Date initialized? You are aware that Date also contains a time part?

Comment: Exactly so even if 1 millisecond has passed the dates are different, you probably need to format them first and then compare them, or do a difference between them and if you only care about day difference check if the diff is less than 24 hours (that would mean its within the same day)

Comment: No, you are not getting yesterdays date but when printed it is using UTC time zone and not your local. Note that now your method can be reduced to a single line `openDate > Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: Date())`

Answer (score 0):

You are not initialising MINIMUM_Date properly. Initialize current date object on run time when function is called

```
func validateDate(openDate: Date) -> Bool 

   var isValid: Bool = true          
   var MINIMUM_Date = Date()               
    if openDate < MINIMUM_Date {
        isValid = false
    }
            
    return isValid
}
```